# Why true != 'none' equals false?

Tags: php

Why true != 'none' equals false?

```
<?php

 var_dump(true != 'none');
 var_dump(true !== 'none');
```

Results

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

Comment: The answer is almost certainly "Type Coercion."

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php